# Null reference exception while using Syncfusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, telerik, syncfusion

I have changed from vs 2010 to 2012 with asp.net MVC4.I have connected my application to the database using Telerik open Access.

I am implementing syncfusion in my application.
I have two issues,

1.Getting Null Reference Exception(Object does not set to an instance of an object) at

```
@Html.Syncfusion().CaptchaControl("Captcha1").EnableRefreshImage(true).RequestMapper("RefreshCaptcha").
```

2.while connecting my apln to the database using telerik open access it is showing error that "ModelContext does not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1: Getting Null Reference Exception(Object does not set to an instance of an object)

The reported issue occurred due to the unavailability of Syncfusion.Theme.Base dll in your application. Syncfusion has introduced a new assembly “Syncfusion.Theme.Base” in the latest version 10.3.0.43 for theming support. so refer the Syncfusion.Theme.Base dll in your application and add the Syncfusion.Theme.Base assembly in web.config to overcome this NullReference exception issue. Please refer the below code snippet,

```
   [Web.Config]
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Theme.Base, Version=10.304.0.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
    </assemblies>
```

Query 2: while connecting my apln to the database using telerik open access it is showing error that "ModelContext does not found".

Before providing solution to this query, I would like to know more details on this issue. Could you please let us know the list of Syncfusion controls that you are using in your application, so that I can analyze the issue and provide you a better solution.